# NLogger giving inconsistent data after each run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, logging, nlog

I have used NLog to log the entry and exits of functions in my code. But with different runs of the same Application I am getting different logs. It is a multi threaded application. And I am using async to log the information.

The following is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 

  <targets>
    <target name="asynclogger" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" overflowAction="Grow" queueLimit="100000" batchSize="5000" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="1">
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="D:\IALogs\${processname}_${processid}_${threadid}.ialog"  layout ="${longdate} ${processname} ${processid} ${threadid} ${mdlc:item=threadid} ${level} ${message}"/>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="asynclogger" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

The following is the logger code.

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly NLog.Logger nLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread th1 = new Thread(() => print(5000000));
            th1.Start();

            Thread th2 = new Thread(() => print(5000000));

            th2.Start();

            th1.Join();
            th2.Join();

            print(10000);

            Console.WriteLine("Done!!!!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void print(int noOfItems)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= noOfItems; i++)
            {
                nLogger.Info("Printing i =" + i);
            }
        }
    }
```

With Console.Readline() the logs are completely written,
if there is no Console.Readline() the logs are different each time and also
the third Print method call from the main thread doesn't log anything if there is no Console.Readline(). If Console.Readline() is present then the 3rd print statement logs all the information

Comment: Please show us the logger code :)

Comment: Please elaborate on "getting different logs"

Comment: @Julian By different logs I mean that by running the same application twice I am getting different logs.

Comment: How different? Please show some examples. (And please edit post)

Comment: @Julian I have edited the post. Let me know if you require any other information.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your sentence "I am getting different logs" should be translated to "I am missing some logs".

When enabling async-operations for NLog targets, then it is important to flush, because writing happens on background threads. Must wait for these, before exiting the application:

```
NLog.LogManager.Flush()
```

See also: [NLog Tutorial - Remember to flush](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#5-remember-to-flush)

Comment: No shutdown as recommendation?

Comment: There is an exception when NLog.LogManager.Flush() was used, Unhandled Exception: OutOfMemoryException. but the internal logs of nlog didnt report any exception. The logs were still missing. And no extra information is available in NLog Internal logs file.
Same exception is seen when NLog.LogManager.Shutdown() is used, but this time there is an exception reported in the internal logs of nlog. The problem with missing logs still persists.
Posting the internal log file error in the next comment.

Comment: 2020-02-19 08:29:10.0979 Error Error with flush. Exception: NLog.NLogRuntimeException: Asynchronous exception has occurred. ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NLog.Common.AsyncHelpers.RunSynchronously(AsynchronousAction action)
   at NLog.LogFactory.Flush(TimeSpan timeout)

Comment: @TasheerHussain The timeout comes from NLog needing more than 15 secs to flush all items. Guessing the issue is that all LogEvents are written to the async-in-memory-buffer, and when doing the the Flush, then all items are written in one operation. Writing all items in one operation is a slow task, compared to multiple operations. You can try and enable keepFileOpen=true. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Performance#file-logging-performance

Comment: @RolfKristensen I found the problem, I was getting incomplete logs because some of the logs were still in the queue, even after the application had completed it's execution. And now when I used NLog.LogManager.flush() , before the application exits, I am getting complete logs. But I do not want to change the source code of the application, is it possible to do this in the NLog.config file?

Comment: @TasheerHussain If you read the Wiki-page in my original answer, then you will see that you should always call `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()` just before application exit (no matter what).